# C++. Сортировка слиянием

Tags: c++, алгоритм, сортировка

Вроде как алгоритм верный, но результат не выводит. Подскажите в чем проблема.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

void mergeSort(vector<int> &vec, int start, int end)
{
    if(end - start < 2) return;

    if(end - start == 2)
    {
        if(vec[start] > vec[start + 1])
            swap(vec[start], vec[start + 1]);

        return;
    }

    mergeSort(vec, start, (end - start) / 2);
    mergeSort(vec, (end - start) / 2, end);

    vector<int> buffer;
    int begin1 = start, end1 = (end - start) / 2, begin2 = end1;

    while(buffer.size() < end - start) 
    {
        if((begin1 >= end1) || ( (begin2 < end) && (vec[begin2] <= vec[begin1]) ) )
        {
            buffer.push_back(vec[begin2]);
            begin2++;
        }
        else
        {
            buffer.push_back(vec[begin1]);
            begin1++;
        }
    }

    for(int i=start; i<end; i++)
        vec[i] = buffer[i - start];
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> vec;

    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
        vec.push_back(i);

    srand(time(NULL));
    for(unsigned int i=0; i<vec.size(); i++)
        swap(vec[i], vec[rand() % (vec.size() - i) + i]);

    for(unsigned int i=0; i<vec.size(); i++)
        cout << vec[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;

    mergeSort(vec, 0, vec.size());

    for(unsigned int i=0; i<vec.size(); i++)
        cout << vec[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

В трех местах нужно `(end-start)/2` заменить на `(end+start)/2`:

```
mergeSort(vec, start, (end + start) / 2);
mergeSort(vec, (end + start) / 2, end);

vector<int> buffer;
int begin1 = start, end1 = (end + start) / 2, begin2 = end1;
```

Вам же нужна средина отрезка, а не половина его длины...

Answer (score -1):

Проблема в том что он у тебя уходит в бесконечную рекурсию и у тебя заканчивается стек для хранения переменных и кидает SIGSEGV. Ну или работает очень долго и не завершается(зависит от размера стека).

вангую что ошибка где то в

```
mergeSort(vec, start, (end - start) / 2);
mergeSort(vec, (end - start) / 2, end);
```

рекомендую заменить end на size.(так будет лаконичней смотреться и легче дебажить)

То есть копай в сторону **условия выхода из рекурсии**.